# Are there any other meanings for "belie??"

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

Sorry for my asking again in this short term, but somehow I ended up finding another one on SAO volume 6, followed by the volume 5 I brought up in the latest question. 
So I want you to help me get what I don't get again. Thanks.

There's a word "belie" which I figured only means "to turn your back on someone close" or "whether deliberately or not, to inform something incorrect." 
And here's a sentence this understanding doesn't seem to work on. But first of all I'd like to tell you what's going on there.

Oh, probably another little spoiler for SAO believers!:

*Dyne, who does very good at this Bullet of Bullet, or some kind of gun-shooting championship where the participants fire at each other till everyone besides one the only winner goes down, is now on his stomach on the shore, after leaving forest and racing down the long bridge within a few seconds to throw himself into ambush for shooting his opponent, who's supposedly about to appear onto the bridge from the other side, untill he's content.*

*Now he's thinking he got his prey completely, but behind Dyne is hiding two players too.*

The following sentences are one out of them's thoughts.

> ***"Dyne was still down in firing position on this side of the long bridge. The way he held the SG 550 straight, without a single twitch,
>   belied an impressive level of concentration..."***

Before I talk about what's driving me nuts, I really want to know what you thought is the problem if there'd be any.

Okay.
Now let me tell you for him what author, an original writer must've intended to say. What's written there in Japanese.

***The way he held the SG 550 straight, without a single twitch----indeed, he seems to have an impressive level of concentration from here.***

Yes, I could be misunderstanding the translated one, I admit it. If anything, I want to admit it.
But I feel like something is strange about this. It's little...different from other translation fails.
Because, you know, if my common sense's still working, it's supposed to be a total opposite translate, is it??

It was thus that, after a few attempts to grasp what on earth the translater meant to say, I was stuck. Have come up with nothing so far. It just doesn't make any sense to me yet.

Little longer than before, and to think that the last one is already too much longer...if it tired you out to read all of this, I'm sorry.
Anyway if you could give me the answer to this, I'd very happy. Thanks.

Comment: In this sense "belied" is being used to mean "betrayed", a common use of the term, even if dictionaries do not explicitly support it.

Comment: 1. to show to be untrue; contradict 2. to misrepresent; disguise the nature of ⇒ *the report belied the real extent of the damage* 3. to fail to justify; disappoint -- http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/belie See also http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belie  and  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/belie

Answer (score 1):

*Belie* has two meanings.  The first is to betray or contradict, in the English idiom, to give the lie to:

> Court transcripts showed that his sworn testimony **belied** his later claims.

The second meaning is to give a false impression:

> His youthful appearance **belied** his age.

The second meaning is applicable to the translation.  The sense of the original is that holding the weapon straight and without twitching is an indication of concentration.  The meaning of the translation is that such a stance is an indication of a casual manner, which is not Dyne's mental state: he's actually concentrating hard, indeed at an "impressive level", and thus the casual manner gives a false impression.

A straight arm and a steady aim doesn't strike me as casual, so perhaps the translator misunderstood the passage. Or misunderstood what *belie* means, thinking that he was expressing something like

> He held the SG 550 straight, without a single twitch, and was thus beheld to have an impressive level of concentration...

That's impossible to tell without consulting the translator.

Comment: I'm totally agreed with "A straight arm and a steady aim doesn't strike me as casual, so perhaps the translator misunderstood the passage." And he most definitely did, I guess. Maybe, with all due respect for your support, it can be ridiculous to be involved in and worried about this probably misunderstood sentence any longer. But anyway, It was a really huge help! Thank you, uh, deadrat!

Comment: There is a further meaning (which one could say belies the first):  To show something to be false -- a "tell" in poker, eg.